# jQuery getting object level this

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I had the following code:

```
var Object = function() {
  this.alert = function() {
    alert("Hello World!");
  }
}

Object.prototype.bindTo = function(element) {
  var me = this;
  $(element).bind('click', function() {
    //this.alert(); //this refrences element
    me.alert(); 
  });
}
```

My question is wether this is the best practice to call the Object.alert() function. Using this.alert() would try and get the element as the 'this' object. What are the current stands for this sort of situation?

Comment: Seems fine to me, other than using the same name as the native alert, which could cause confusion !

Comment: That is the default choice, AFAIK.

Comment: Hopefully you'll use another name than `Object`, right ?

Comment: Why do you use a prototype level function for bindTo and an instance level function for alert ?

Comment: there is nothing wrong, this code is default practice

Comment: Here's how I'd do it -> http://jsfiddle.net/pHL29/

Comment: Are you overwriting the Alert event?

Comment: Object and alert were just used for the sake of example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `bind` to change the meaning of `this` inside a function...

```
Object.prototype.bindTo = function(element) {
    $(element).bind('click', function() {
        this.alert(); //this references whatever you put inside bind()
    }.bind(this));
}
```

**[See the documentation here...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)**